# Old EJB client backwards compatibility

Tags: jboss, migration, ejb, redhat, ejb-2.x

I'm migrating old applications from JBoss EAP 6.4 to JBoss EAP 7.3 and I have a strange behaviour. I setup the remote connector on EAP 7.3 and both 2.1 and 3.x EJB applications are deployed, but if I try connect from an old client, having a very old jboss client jar (1.0.25.Final-redhat-1) I have some errors.

The 3.x applications work without problem and in JBoss EAP 7.3 I can see this log when a call arrives

```
INFO [org.wildfly.naming] (default task-1) Wildfly Naming version 1.0.11.Final-redhat-00001
```

For the 2.1 EJB application (that works without problem on the old JBoss EAP 6.4) I see this different log on the server console

```
INFO [org.jboss.ejb.client] (default task-2) JBoss EJB Client version 4.0.27.Final-redhat-00001
```

and from the client side I receive this error

```
INFO: Cannot create a scoped EJB client context for JNDI naming context     org.jboss.ejb.client.naming.ejb.EjbNamingContext@abb9e4 since the current EJB client context selector can't handle scoped contexts
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.create(Unknown Source)
at com.test.ejbmigration.EjbRemoteClient.main(EjbRemoteClient.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBIdentifier
```

I found an old issue related to this problem that is quite similar

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/EJBCLIENT-51

but anyway I think it isn't the same situation. Using a new client with new library there is no problem, but in my scenario I have the possibility to have an EJB 2.x application in EAP 7.3 and old client calling it in the same way.

I would like to understand if the migration of old EJB 2.x applications to EAP 7.3 and remote call from old clients can be a problem or if there is some particular settings that can be done on the server to accept also the call from old client.

Comment: The `NoClassDef` error seems like the root cause. Checking transitive dependencies might help. They are unavailable in the question.

Comment: EJBIdentifier is something available in new ejb-client library (for example in the one present on JBoss EAP 7.3). But anyway it isn't something that the client should have, also because in other call (the EJB3 example) we haven't this exception

Comment: From the question, the error shows on the client side. The details of [scoped contexts](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Scoped%20EJB%20client%20contexts.html) refer to this [enhancement](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/EJBCLIENT-34) which appears in 1.0.13. It seems that the application context as returned has a breaking change in the format.

Comment: Yes but the problem is that also a new test application (EJB 3) deployed in the new application server works without problem using this old client (a main client that calls old EJB 2.x and EJB 3 both deployed in new application server)

Comment: The question says that the old client has issues with a EJB 2.x application on a EAP 7 server. What is the configuration creating an issue ?

Comment: Yes this is the problem, old client with EJB 2.x app on EAP 7. But using the same old client with EJB 3 on EAP 7 it works.

Comment: Class loading might be the cause. There a number of ways to organize it. This [documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/18/Developer_Guide.html#jboss-deployment-structure-file) explains some principles. In all, EJB3 is doing the work but EJB2 seems to require more attention.